# PLACEHOLDER - A place holder post for the Gremlify app

Tags: app, placeholder

gremlify.com is a free platform for visualizing and querying graphs using Gremlin.

Similar to JSFiddle for JS, Gremlify does the same thing for the Gremlin query language.

This app will help the Gremlin community by allowing Gremlify users to create high-quality questions, that include reproduction steps, a prettified query, and more.

Comment: How does this app use the Stack Exchange API or adds capabilities to the existing features of the sites within the SE Network?

Comment: By allowing users create high quality questions, that include reproduction steps, a prettified query and more.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add all the relevant details directly into the question body.